# IntelliJ IDEA / JetBrains IDEs: How to hide file last changed timestamp in the project view?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-toolbox

Hi how can I hide files timestamp? Can some one help?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

View | Appearance | Details in Tree View (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>):

[image: Details in Tree View]